# using css pixel calculating screen size, where is wrong?

Tags: css, web, retina-display, w3c

In css w3([here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#x39)),

`1px = 0.75pt, 1pt = 2.54/72 cm,` so 1 css pixel:`1px = 0.26mm`

for example, the **CSS pixel** of iPhone4 is 320px * 480px(not device pixel),
so in width ,the length should be:

```
320 *0.26 = 83.2mm
```

but the iPhone4 is 3.5"，so the length in width is about `60mm`,

it dont match the result i calculated above
where is wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSS pixel is not always 0.26mm

From CSS W3:

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm's length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

The iPhone4 is not 96dpi. With a device pixel ratio of 2, its "CSS dpi" is around 163. Since 96dpi devices render 320px at 83.2mm, mathematically, 163dpi devices should render 320px at 49mm.

Comment: thanks, but what is css dpi, how to get the value of a device ?

Comment: iPhone4 has a published DPI of 326. But in CSS, it typically has a device pixel ratio of 2, so in essence, CSS displays 326/2 = 163px per inch. Anyway, I doubt "CSS dpi" is the official term, hence the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The physical unit is based on 96dpi, therefore 1in in css is 96px, so 3.5in = 336px. Here's a blog post which can explain this: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/11/the_css_physica.html but it's also mentioned in the W3 spec you posted if you scroll down a bit.

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length.

Comment: on 96 dpi , 1in = 96px = 72pt，so when on high dpi(163 dpi),so 1in = 163px = 122pt?

Comment: No, 1in is always 96px, 1in is never 163px.

Comment: 3.5in[336px] is the diagonal line，but right-angle side is 320 * 480, 336 is smaller than 480

Comment: the physical unit px is based on 96dpi, but the in css, the px is reference value, isn't it ? the physical value: 336px convert to 336*(163/96) px in css?right?